# Can hdf4 images be used in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, hdf

I'm trying to use hdf4 raster image in QGis 1.8. This image come from the [MODIS](http://www.ntsg.umt.edu/project/modis) satellite. I've loaded the file, it appears on the layer window bu it is impossible to see it on the display window.

Did someone already work with hdf images on QGis?

Thanks

Comment: I tried with a sample download, but only got nice geometric designs. Project CRS should be set to 4326. There are a lot of open tickets for HDF4 support in GDAL: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/HDF

Comment: Can you give us a little more about the data? Are you sure the raster is an image? Which MODIS layer is it? Can you post a link to the file? Just for starters, :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115101/how-to-properly-open-an-aster-data