# Opening *.hdf file from ASTER in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, hdf, aster

I am trying to open *.hdf file from ASTER in QGIS and it can not recognize CRS. Does anybody knows solution to this?

Comment: it looks like you need to do a bit of work with gdal tools to extract the raster you need to tiff and build the crs metadata. See [this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/115126/55203)

Comment: I try this with gdalinfo and gdalwarp but it is not working, the images stay the same. It is maybe because I have downloaded ASTER 1LT, bit 1B as it was in answer